# Joomla 3.8.11 Intro image not loading

Tags: php, joomla

I have a problem with intro image in articles, not loading images, 404 error.
Inserting `%0A` characters in front of index.php in the URL.
Analyzing the problem with inspect element on select button i have found that in front of url there is characters `%0A` (LF line feed) and directing on unexisting location -

`href="/website/%0Aindex.php?option=com_jce&view=editor&plugin=browser&standalone=1&4fedf313d9a5bcc55fd7482d1fccb5e3=1&context=22&mediatype=images&fieldid=jform_images_image_intro&folder=`

[image: img]

When i remove `%0A` characters in inspect element mode images are loading with no problems. Also if i turn debugging on, these `%0A` characters are missing and intro images are loading.

Comment: add the code which renders that href part